How easy is it for a thief to repurpose a stolen, non-rooted Android phone with both a SIM card PIN and a phone PIN?
I recently dropped a phone and I assume somebody picked it up and ran with it since it was immediately turned off.
Now I want to know how easy is it to get into the phone which is running Android 12 (as far as I remember) and has a PIN on both the SIM card itself and the phone?
Is there a method that would allow the perpetrator to factory reset the phone without knowing what the PIN is?
I already went to Find my Device and instructed Google to factory reset the phone the next time it connects to the internet but so far, it has not been successful at resetting it. I always have data on so it could either mean the thief has not been able to unlock it or they have successfully factory reset it and are using a different Google account on it now.
To be honest, I'd prefer the latter scenario so the perpetrator can just happily use the phone instead of browsing through my private files.

"they have successfully factory reset it and are using a different Google account on it now" if they do a factory reset (which is possible), then they will face the [tag:factory-reset-protection] instead (and probably sell it to an unfortunate buyer...).

@AndrewT. How does one factory reset a phone without knowing the PIN? I have never heard of FRP until now, what a useful feature!

OEM allows force restart by long pressing the power button. Then the attacker can go into recovery mode to factory reset the device.
